# How to specify scopes when granting OAUTH token for Firebase using solely the web api

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, oauth

I am writing a server-side application which will access Firebase using a service-role key. I am able to grant an OAUTH token without issue from following the Firebase API documentation, but one part that it does not mention is how to specify the required scopes. Currently, when I try to access any of the services after getting an OAUTH token (from the service-role account) I get a "insufficient permissions" error. What is the correct way to specify the scopes when authenticating manually? My code is written in Rust but I'm just looking for a general solution.

My current method of specifying the scopes is to include them in the claims object when granting the token:

```
let claims = Claims {
            alg: "RS256".to_string(),
            iss: service_role_email.to_string(),
            sub: service_role_email.to_string(),
            aud: "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit".to_string(),
            iat: current_time_str,
            exp: expire_time_str,
            uid: uuid_str,
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email".to_string()
};
```

But this clearly isn't working as I get this permissions error even when I dont include the scopes this way.